SFML setting origin of sf::Text not working
I came across a problem trying to draw text to the screen. In a class a draw function is called avery frame when drawing and it does:
sf::Text text("1000", font, 50);
text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
text.setOrigin(text.getLocalBounds().getSize()/2.f);
text.setPosition(window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)));

window.draw(text);

but when I run this the text's center is not where the cursor is:

For debbuging I tried to add a rectangle:
sf::RectangleShape rect(dealerText.getLocalBounds().getSize());
rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
rect.setOrigin(dealerText.getLocalBounds().getSize()/2.f);
rect.setPosition(window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)));

window.draw(rect);

and this draws correctly even though it does the same thing as the text:


Possibly related: SFML#2172 and SFML#2988

You can find first letter position (in global bounds), and you can calculate the difference between text element position, add this difference to text element position.
findCharacterPos function documentation
